# Dynamically pass country code to @IsPhoneNumber() based on user input

Tags: node.js, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I have a DTO which utilizes class validators as follows.

```
export class RandomlyNamedDto {
  @IsRequired()
  @Max(3)
  @Min(2)
  countryCode: string;
  
  @IsPhoneNumber()
  phone: string;
}
```

I want to pass the country code to `@IsPhoneNumber()` based on the country code sent by the user. For example if countryCode = 'UK' the validator will be like follows.

`IsPhoneNumber('UK')`

Comment: I think you'll struggle using decorators. I've never managed to get it to work and always resort to manual validation. I looked over class-validator docs and it seems a custom validator *may* work? Anyway, I'd look at `isPhoneNumber` and call it in a method instead. It's not a clean solution but it does work. https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a custom decorator and registering it with the class-validator library.
The code below is [adapted from another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253182/6609994) to fit your criteria:

```
import {
  ValidationOptions,
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationArguments,
  buildMessage,
  IsDefined,
  validate,
  isPhoneNumber,
  MaxLength,
  MinLength,
} from "class-validator";

export function IsPhoneNumberForRegion(
  property: string,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
      registerDecorator({
        name: "isPhoneNumberForRegion",
        target: object.constructor,
        propertyName: propertyName,
        constraints: [property],
        options: validationOptions,
        validator: {
            validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
              // the property name that holds the country code
              const [countryCodeField] = args.constraints;

              // the value of the country code on the target object
              const countryCode = (args.object as any)[countryCodeField];

              // validate phone number for specified region
              return isPhoneNumber(value, countryCode);
            },
            // specify custom error message
            defaultMessage: buildMessage(
            (eachPrefix) =>
              `${eachPrefix} $property must be a valid phone number in the specified region`,
            validationOptions
            ),
        },
    });
  };
}

class ExampleUsage {
  @IsDefined()
  @MaxLength(3)
  @MinLength(2)
  countryCode: string;

  @IsPhoneNumberForRegion("countryCode")
  phone: string;

  constructor(countryCode: string, phone: string) {
    this.phone = phone;
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
  }
}

(async () => {
  const exampleGood = new ExampleUsage("US", "(201)-867-5309");
  const validationPasses = await validate(exampleGood);
  console.log(validationPasses);

  const exampleErrors = new ExampleUsage("US", "not a phone number");
  const validationWithErrors = await validate(exampleErrors);
  console.log(validationWithErrors);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a pipe:

```
import { PipeTransform, ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsPhoneNumber, validate } from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class PhoneNumberPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
    private countryKey: string
    private phoneKey: string
    constructor(
        countryKey: string,
        phoneKey: string
    ) {
        this.countryKey = countryKey
        this.phoneKey = phoneKey
    }
    async transform(value, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
        if (value[this.countryKey]) {
            class PhoneNumberDto {
                @IsPhoneNumber(value[this.countryKey])
                phone: string;
            }

            const phoneNumberDto = plainToClass(PhoneNumberDto, { phone: value[this.phoneKey] });

            const errorsFields = await validate(phoneNumberDto);

            if (errorsFields.length > 0) {
                throw new BadRequestException(errorsFields);
            }

            return {
                ...value,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller call it just like that:

```
@UsePipes(new PhoneNumberPipe('countryCode', 'phone'))
async userSignup(@Res() res, @Body() body: SignUpDto) {
  // sign up logic here
}
```